# My Bluetooth mouse freezes while being actively used

Tags: bluetooth, intel, ubuntu-mate

My BT freezes up while I'm using it. It actually comes back to life if I put the laptop to sleep and wake it up, but to be fair I have a connect script in /etc/pm/sleep.d from when 16.04 was not waking my network up. If I leave the "About" dialog box open in blueman-manager, it does not lock up. I have disabled the BT script in /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d to see if that helped, it did not.

My current work around is to open up blueman-manager, open the about dialog and then just move them both to another workspace where they are out of the way.

Possible pertinent hardware info:

- Processor     : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710MQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
- Memory            : 12233MB
- Operating System  : Ubuntu 16.10
- Network controller    : Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
- HP Bluetooth Laser Mobile Mouse

---

My connect script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
        resume|thaw)
        nmcli nm sleep false
         systemctl restart networking
         bluetoothctl connect 00:0F:F6:6D:46:38
 ;;
esac
```

Comment: I posted my script. Timing is random.

Comment: My workaround has stopped working. Now it just dies anyway. I can close the laptop up for a few seconds and then log back in and it is fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on Mint 19.3 with a Microsoft Arc Mouse. It kept freezing at random intervals. The only way to get it working again was to shut the mouse down (in the case of Arc mouse this means un-arcing and re-arcing (is this even English?) it). Somehow I solved this by booting Mint with an older kernel (in GRUB, I jumped back some 4 versions). Using that kernel I removed the mouse (in Bluetooth), paired and connected it. And it worked flawlessly. After booting again in the latest (default) kernel. The mouse kept working as it should. No idea why but this worked for me. Goo luck!